# How to get Last Name of a Person from CSV file in flutter if First Name is selected by user?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, csvreader

Just to simplify my question , How to get Last Name of a Person from CSV file in flutter if First Name is selected by user from specific data given to him in Dropdown ?

Eg: If User select Tom in dropdown menu the Text widget should yeild Cruise

Data type is given in Image attached

**Thanks in advance**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud5vr.png)

Comment: If I was doing this in Excel, I would use index() with match(), as long as the first names are unique.

Comment: i know how to do this in excel , need help with doing this in flutter

Comment: Ah, confused as you tagged Excel…